# executing web service using postman

Tags: apex, webservices

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Merchandise/*')
global with sharing class MerchandiseManager {

    @HttpGet
    global static Merchandise__c getMerchandiseById() {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;        
        String merchId = req.requestURI.substring(
                                  req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        Merchandise__c result = 
                       [SELECT Name,Description__c,Price__c,Total_Inventory__c
                        FROM Merchandise__c 
                        WHERE Id = :merchId];
        return result;
    }

    @HttpPost
    global static String createMerchandise(String name,
        String description, Decimal price, Double inventory) {
        Merchandise__c m = new Merchandise__c(
            Name=name,
            Description__c=description,
            Price__c=price,
            Total_Inventory__c=inventory);
        insert m;
        return m.Id;
    }
}
```

i am trying to execute these from postman,

https://na8.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/MerchandiseManager?name=GenePoint

but throwing below error,how i can authenticate,please help urgent requirement.

> {
>       "message": "Session expired or invalid",
>       "errorCode": "INVALID_SESSION_ID"   }

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't connect Salesforce without authentication so you need to first generate app key and secret and then you will use that to call your api.

You can follow below steps:

1. Create Connected app in salesforce from Setup->Create-> Apps

[image]

2. After successful completion of previous step you will get consumer key and consumer secret as shown below.

[image]

3. Open postman and input setup as shown below

[image]

4. Copy access token and instance url for next step.

[image]

5. Connect to your rest api endpoint (https://na8.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/MerchandiseManager?name=GenePoint)

[image]

Ref document : http://sfdcbeginner.com/how-to-test-salesforce-rest-api.html

Comment: Hi HImansu,i cant see form over there,developer edition can make use of postaman/!

Comment: yes you can use developer edition.

Comment: i had added Advanced REST Api,i entered url like https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token,,i can see form over there

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: 400 bad request

Comment: are you passing app secret and key?

Comment: where should pass?!can please tel me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45258/discussion-between-himanshu-and-sahisfdc).

Comment: Does grant-type = password still work?

Comment: @mkorman yes grant-type=password still works

Comment: Hi mkorman,did check it ?!

Comment: @sahisfdc I posted this answer with workable solution.

Comment: sorry himanchu,,token is not genrating for me,if i click request password,asking for username and password,then just logged in succesffully

Comment: where are you getting request password option?

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote an article exactly on how to connect to Salesforce using Postman.

As @Himanshu mentioned, you need to define a connected app to authenticate to.

I hope you find the article useful: http://blog.mkorman.uk/using-postman-to-explore-salesforce-restful-web-services/

Comment: where can i see client id

Comment: it's defined in your connected app in Salesforce.

Comment: is it consumer key

Comment: what is Auth URL and Access Token URL,,i did not see any urls with this name.

Comment: Those are well-known URL's, and they are mentioned in the post above: `https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize` and `https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token`

Comment: hi i tried with above url ,,,the auth url which u gave is not working,i tried with https://login.salesforce.com,not throwing any error but token is not added,it simply asking for username and password,successfully logged in,

Comment: @mkorman While your blog may address the issue, it is good form to include relevant content here.